# Get all the possible permutations and combinations given min and max number

Tags: algorithm

I have suppose two places: `-,-` .Each of these place has a max limit. Such as `first place has max limit` of `3` and `2nd place has max limit` of `7`.

I have other 2 numbers which is  `totalmaxlimit` and other is `totalminlimit`.

```
Ex; totalmaxlimit  = 6
    totalminlimit = 3
```

I want to write a code where I can fill above two places with all possible permutation and combinations such that the sum of three places is greater than equal to 3 and less than equal to 6.

```
Example:

3 0  
3 1 
2 0 
2 1
2 4

Also,

2 6 will be wrong result because sum is greater than totalmaxlimit.
4 2 is also wrong as first place has max limit of 3.
```

Code in any language is fine. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a first attempt, you should sit down with a pencil and a paper, and work out the solution for a couple of sample values. Hint: draw it as a table with the first number as the row and the second as a column and observe the shape of the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that:

1) The place is given by A, B coordinates
2) You have a totalMin (m) and a totalMax (M)
3) The rules are that A, B, and A+B should be >= m and <=M
4) The amount of values is given by the equation M-m. (e.g, if M =10 and m=0, we will have 10 valid values).

You can get a permutation by using the formula P = n! / (n-k)! where N is you number of values, and k is the valid numbers you can have.

So, for example, if m = 0, M = 6:

Permutations = (0,6) , (1,5), (2,4), etc...

Basically you have the sum of (X_n, X_M) where, when n grows, M decreases. M = M - n

I hope this helps for now, but I can provide a more 'profissional' formula if you like. The language could be python because I think it would be easier. But first you need to get the algorithm, passing it to code is trivial.

Here's the code:

```
def permutations(min, max):
# init variables
m = min
M = max
results = []

# main loop
for i in range(min, max):
    for j in range(min, max):
        if ((i + j) >= min and (i+j) <= max ):
            results.append([i, j])

print(results)
```

Comment: Sure, I can code it in python, but I won't be able to test it since i'm currently at work. give me a sec

Comment: Thanks , It would be fine.

Comment: I think it's best for everybody if OP works the algorithm out for him/herself, given that this is obviously homework.

Comment: If you have python installed you can open the file, call for example: permutation(0, 6). And then on the terminal just run python name_of_file.py